# How can I retrieve WPA keys?

Tags: ubuntu, wpa2-psk

I use Ubuntu 12.04.1

I try iwlist, but it is what I have:

```
user@comp-1:~$ sudo iwlist wlan0 keys
wlan0     2 key sizes : 40, 104bits
          4 keys available :
        [1]: off
        [2]: off
        [3]: off
        [4]: off
          Current Transmit Key: [1]
user@comp-1:~$ sudo iwlist wlan0 wpakeys
wlan0     2 key sizes : 40, 104bits
          4 keys available :

Error reading wpa keys (SIOCGIWENCODEEXT): Operation not supported
```

I want know WPA key for give it to wpa_supplicant. I tried use wpa_passphrase, but I have follow line in log:

```
WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
```